# How do I replace %<string> with the parameters

Tags: javascript

I am getting API response like this.

```
{
  "message": "The password needs at least %1 characters. Password should be having %param2 special characters in it. Create a new password and try again.",
  "parameters": [
    "8",
    "param2test"
  ]
}
```

Here I should search if I have %[string] in the response, if its there I need to replace %1 with the first array element of parameters, %2 with second and so on. There could be n number of parameters. How can I do this in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const r = {
    "message": "The password needs at least %1 characters. Password should be having %2 special characters in it. Create a new password and try again.",
    "parameters": [
        "8",
        "2"
    ]
}

const parameterizedString = (...args) => {
    const [str, ...params] = args;
    return str.replace(/%\d+/g, matchedStr => {
        const variableIndex = matchedStr.replace("%", "") - 1;
        return params[variableIndex];
    });
}
console.log(parameterizedString(r.message, ...r.parameters))
```

Comment: I have updated the question, please check if you can answer it @reifocs

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {
  "message": "The password needs at least %1 characters. Password should be having %2 special characters in it. Create a new password and try again.",
  "parameters": [
    "8",
    "2"
  ]
};


function change({ message, parameters }) {
  let str = message;

  message.match(/(%[0-9]+)/g).forEach((item, i) => {
    str = str.replace(item, parameters[i]);
  })

  return str;
}

console.log(change(obj));
```

Comment: The issue with this is suppose I have %1 %2 %100 in string it still matches the third element of the array

Comment: its supposed be like that, isn't it suppose to do it for any number of `%[number]` in the message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const obj = {
  "message": "The password needs at least %1 characters. Password should be having %2 special characters in it. Create a new password and try again.",
  "parameters": [
    "8",
    "2"
  ]
}

const regex = /%\d/g;
function f(match){
  const m = Number(match.slice(1))
  return obj.parameters[m-1]
}
```